# Multiple data sources/series requests from from (BLS)API using only URL

Tags: python, api

i'm trying to request multiple series of data from the bureau of labor statistics using their API. I know how to do it with JSON/python

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({"seriesid": ['SMU17169740000000001','SMU17169740500000001','SMU17169740600000001','SMU17169740700000001','SMU17169740800000001','SMU17169741000000001',
                                'SMU17169742000000001'],"registrationkey":"28276365193b4a089838d62e522d2a63","startyear":"2011", "endyear":"2021"})
p = requests.post('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
print (p.url)
json_data = json.loads(p.text)
```

(which returns perfectly)
However, i'm trying to do it with a single URL that can be pasted into any web browser; like so

```
https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/SMU17169743000000001?&catalog=true&startyear=2010&endyear=2021&calculations=true%20&annualaverage=true,
```

But obviously that only returns from a single time series; SMU17169743000000001

And I dont know how to include any more series IDs (eg SMU17169740800000001) in the URL request.

https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_signature_v2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BLS documentation clearly states that for multiple series, the HTTP method is 'post' and not 'get':

```
Multiple Series
Use this signature to retrieve data for more than one timeseries ...

HTTP Type:  POST
```

This means that there's no URL you can just paste into your browser. You can, however, use a variety of tools to manually run post requests. One of the more popular ones in [postman](https://www.postman.com/), and there are also various Chrome extensions that can serve as rest clients - for example [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

Comment: ah i did get as far as that i was post, but not get. I didnt know that that meant there was no URL. (Havent done much with APIs or Get/POSTs)